# Range of values of $x$ for which the expansion $\ln(2+x)$ to valid

Tags: taylor-expansion

It is known that 
$$\ln(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty{(-1)^{n+1} \dfrac{x^n}{n}}$$ for $-1<x\leq1$.

Question: What is the range of values of $x$ for which the expansion of $\ln(2+x)$ is valid?

I rewrite it as follows:

$$\ln(2+x) = \ln (1 + (1 + x))$$

Then I use the expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ above to obtain the expansion of $\ln(2+x)$. In this case, I obtain the range of values of $x$ is $-1 <1+x \leq 1 \Rightarrow -2 < x \leq 0$.

However, if I rewrite 
$$\ln(2+x) = \ln (2(1 + \dfrac{x}{2})) = \ln 2 + \ln (1 + \dfrac{x}{2})$$ 
The range of values of $x$ is $-1 < \frac{x}{2} \leq 1 \Rightarrow -2 < x \leq 2$, which is different from what I obtain above.

Which inequality is true? If $-2 < x  \leq 0$ is false, what is the reason?

Comment: The two series provide distinct representations of $\log(2+x)$.  They have different intervals over which they represent $\log(2+x)$.

Comment: They are both correct but with different radius of convergence ($|x|<2$ and $|1+x|<1$).